On Ubuntu 24.04, llvm-aio is installed but the command clang++ is not found
I feel like I have missed something obvious.
On a fresh install of 24.04 on a new PC, I can see in the output from snap list that the llvm-aio package is installed (I don't recall installing it, but I may have), which is documented to include the clang and clang++ commands, but typing clang++ --version gets me Command clang++ not found, but....  I have tried using auto-complete (clang-[TAB]) with no results.  What am I missing?

It looks like the snap only provides llvm-aio.clang and llvm-aio.clang-plus-plus explicitly in /snap/bin/ - symlinks clang and clang++ are buried in /snap/llvm-aio/2/usr/bin/. I'm not sure what the best practice is here tbh (i.e. should /snap/llvm-aio/2/usr/bin/ be added to your PATH or ... ?)
